# Navigation UIBarButtonItem Appearance On Device Is Different

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a custom bar back button icon that I am using for my navigation controller. I use the following code in the view controllers.

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "previous");
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(myImage, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default);
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

The result during testing was this:

[image: Bar back button item during testing]

But when my app hit the app store the result was this:

[image]

Does anyone know why is the result different and how can I fix the appearance ? Or if not how else can I change the back button item. It is really annoying because my app has a bug that I did not know about and will take 10days to update when I find a fix.

**UPDATE** It seems if the left item has text the image wraps around the text. However I have used a empty string as I cannot use nil because that uses the default text provided by the navigation controller. So the result is some slight wrapping of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "BackButton")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 0))
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImage, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-1000, -1000), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```